# Is there a way to anti-alias a graphics2d object in Java?

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d, antialiasing

I'm not sure if the term "anti-alias" is correct in this instance, I'm quite ignorant about computer graphics, but I'm looking for a way to make the graphics of my Java program look less blocky and jagged. Is there any way to make both the text and shapes of a graphics2d object in Java look more smooth and less pixelated? Is the only solution to apply them at a higher resolution?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html

Comment: Have a look at `Graphics2D#setRenderingHint`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427566/save-jpanel-as-image-hd-quality/28492187#28492187)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed.