# JPanel print attached canvases shows up as blank

Tags: java, swing, canvas, printing, jpanel

I am trying to help my son do math, so I made a small program.
I have a JPanel with 12 Canvases and a giant print button on the bottom.

[image: Window I want to print]

This is the listener I have attached on my print button.

```
    print.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            panel.remove(print);
            window.pack();
            printComponent(panel, false);
            panel.add(print);
            window.pack();
        }
    });
```

I have followed example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916) and sadly it doesn't work.
When I pass JFrame as the component then it prints the whole window!
[image: Window printed!]
When I pass JPanel as the component then it only prints the print button!
[image: Print button only printed!]

If it is of any relevance I attach everything to the JFrame and JPanel like so:

```
panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
panel.setLayout(/*layout stuff*/);
window.setContentPane(panel);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    panel.add(/*canvas class which renders one single question*/);
}
panel.add(print, /*layout constraints*/);
```

I have even tried following examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22244116#22244116) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22242658#22242658) and nothing works.
I can't seem to just print jpanel with the canvas showing up, and I sure as heck do not want to print the whole window.
Any advice on how to fix this?

Here is small example code with same problem.

```
package carefree.school;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestWindow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas()
        {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paint(g);
                g.drawOval(3, 3, 94, 94);
            }
        };
        canvas.setSize(100, 100);
        JButton print = new JButton("Print");
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.add(canvas);
        panel.add(print);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        print.addActionListener(e -> printComponentToFile(panel, false));
    }

    public static void printComponentToFile(Component comp, boolean fill)
    {
        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setSize(8.3 * 72, 11.7 * 72);
        paper.setImageableArea(18, 18, 559, 783);

        PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
        pf.setPaper(paper);
        pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int) Math.round(pf.getWidth()), (int) Math.round(pf.getHeight()),
                                              BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        ComponentPrinter cp = new ComponentPrinter(comp, fill);
        try
        {
            cp.print(g2d, pf, 0);
        }
        finally
        {
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        try
        {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Page-" + (fill ? "Filled" : "") + ".png"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class ComponentPrinter
            implements Printable
    {
        private Component comp;
        private boolean   fill;

        public ComponentPrinter(Component comp, boolean fill)
        {
            this.comp = comp;
            this.fill = fill;
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index)
        {
            if (page_index > 0)
            {
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());

            double width  = (int) Math.floor(format.getImageableWidth());
            double height = (int) Math.floor(format.getImageableHeight());

            if (!fill)
            {

                width = Math.min(width, comp.getPreferredSize().width);
                height = Math.min(height, comp.getPreferredSize().height);

            }

            comp.setBounds(0, 0, (int) Math.floor(width), (int) Math.floor(height));
            if (comp.getParent() == null)
            {
                comp.addNotify();
            }
            comp.validate();
            comp.doLayout();
            comp.printAll(g2);
            if (comp.getParent() != null)
            {
                comp.removeNotify();
            }

            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking about code that is not behaving as expected, a common issue. Also, you're not new here, and so should be quite familiar with the [mre] link, why it is recommended in this situation and why it would be quite helpful for you and for us. So, I have to ask, why not post a valid [mre] code post with your question?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have tried to do so. But the code to generate the problem in question is quite large. I will try to create a quick window with a canvas and a dot then as an example. Sorry about that!

Comment: As you probably know, this is usually the case, and that is why the [mre] link recommends that you create a new small program, one that isolates the problem from the rest of the code so that the issue is easy to see, easy to analyze and easy to fix. Always best to do this before asking, if at all possible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels added! Sorry about that! Made it as small as possible!

Comment: `Canvas` is not the best choice for this, use a `JPanel` instead

Comment: I would, instead, start with a pluggable rendering workflow, which could be used to render directly to any given `Graphics`.  I'd then use it to paint on to a component or a `Printable` directly

Comment: Did you write `ComponentPrinter` yourself?

Comment: @g00se No, it's mine 

Comment: @MadProgrammer yup yup, I linked to your answer. Just had to provide a compilable example, so I included your code. Also thanks for suggesting to use pluggable workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Don't use `Canvas` for this, I'm not sure it's "printable", or at the very least, it didn't work for me.

Instead, extend from `JPanel` instead...

```
JPanel canvas = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(3, 3, 94, 94);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }
};
```

You should also avoid call `setBounds` and prefer to provide sizing hints instead.

Second, choose the component you want to print carefully, for example, in your runnable code, you're passing `panel`, which will print both the button and the circle, instead, you should really only need to pass `canvas`

```
print.addActionListener(e -> printComponentToFile(canvas, false));
```

With these couple of fixes, it now outputs...

[image]

I also thing that `if (comp.getParent() != null) {` is a mistake and instead should be `if (comp.getParent() == null) {`

You may also need to call

```
comp.revalidate();
comp.repaint();
```

after you've printed the component, but this is one of the many issues with trying to print a "live" component.

Personally, I create a concept of a "renderable question", which could be passed a `Graphics` context onto which it should be rendered.

You could then create a "renderable question sheet" which would paint multiple "questions".

This could then be used by both a custom component and `Printable` independently, but that's me.

Comment: How would one know which components are not printable?

Comment: Well, since `Printable` is a `Swing` based concept, I would suggest that only Swing based components are likely to support it.  I would also, personally, discourage the printing of Swing components directly like this, as there are significant differences between screen rendering and paper rendering

Comment: @Quillion See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427566/save-jpanel-as-image-hd-quality/28492187#28492187) for a demonstration of a "renderable" solution