# Export huge JFrame to file

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, bufferedimage

I need to export some visual data generated in Java to PNG files.
The approach I am using in the source code is:

```
//create jframe then draw on it...
jframe.setSize(jrame.getPreferredSize());
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(jframe.getWidth(), jframe.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
jframe.paint(bufferedImage.getGraphics());
jframe.dispose();
```

The problem is that when the drawing is large (because it needs to be), sometimes the exporting failures:

***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=73614 height=73540) are too large***

Exporting just part of the image is not an option for me. What can I export it? Maybe a customized exportation? An external library/API? It is fine for me if it used other image extensions besides png.

EDIT: jframe already handles the height and width scrolls correctly as the content gets bigger then monitor size. The exporting process works for that already as well.

Comment: How big's your screen?

Comment: how do you event get a `JFrame` that is **that** giantic. The actual problem here isn't the fileformat, but simply the size of the image.  
Just a simple calculation:  
70000 * 70000px * 4bytes/px = ~18TB  
This is not the precise size of the image due to several factors like compression, headers, etc. , but it should give atleast a rough reference value for the size of the image. You'll have to save it chunkwise (in case you even got that much free memory though that shouldn't be a problem if you're able to get **that** screen).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I use a 23" monitor, by JFrame applies scroll when it gets big, and large png image files are fine for me as I can apply zoom in and zoom out as I need. I am already exporting images larger than monitor size and this is not an issue.

Comment: @Paul The resulting files aren't that large because of PNG compression.

Comment: But a frame of 73, 614x 73, 540 won't fit on the screen...are you using a `JScrollPane` or any other mechanism to maintain the window to visible screen bounds? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses. You may also need to provide links to example images

Comment: Remember also, you need to be able to hold the uncompressed image data in memory, the compression is only applied while the file is been written

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it uses JScrollPane to handle larger content than monitor size. I have no idea how to produce runnable example since I perform tons of job before the content is actually produced. But I think the important part is all there: how to export JFrame to image file when content being displayed takes too much size? Maybe I should look for exporting such content not as 'image' but as .SVG or such (as I am essentially exporting graphs).

Comment: Well, I tried to create a `BufferedImage` with you dimensions and essentially got a out of memory error (only have 8gb of Ram), so I'm not sure, without breaking the image down into small chunks, how you might export something of that size.  Is it the zoomed size or the "normal" size?

Comment: @IcaroDourado "this is not the precise of the image due to several factors like **compression**..." as I already mentioned in my comment. And compression isn't some magical method to turn TB into MB so the value should do for a rough reference value

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please, and the code needed to reproduce? I always get a `OutOfMemoryError`. Also, note that a normal `BufferedImage` is backed by an array. Your dimensions of `73614 x 73540 = 5413573560` is way beyond `2147483647` (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) which is the theoretical maximum length of an array in Java (most likely, you'll run out of heap space long before that though). Multiply by 4 (as correctly stated by @Paul) and you'll have the number of bytes you would need... Image compression is *not* a factor, `BufferedImage`s are not compressed in memory.

Comment: I think it would be useful (to better understand what your goal is, rather than the problem with the chosen approach) to know *why* your image needs to be this big?

Comment: @ÍcaroDourado you might want to take a look at JAI. I haven't used it myself though

Comment: @MadProgrammer I currently use 14GB for the program

Comment: @haraldK I currently use 14GB for the program. The image really needs to be large, the content itself is large.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving to a PNG file you may want to try some different format, like SVG. This answer on stack overflow dealing with [Apache Batik and SVGGraphics2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/811936/5328408) may be a start.

Comment: I ended up coming to this same conclusion (as I commented here yesterday), mainly because the content I plot in JFrame before exporting to png is a graph, whose API already implements such svg exporting, among other graph file formats. While my original approach works fine for small to medium graphs, png doesn't help when the graphs get too large. Thanks for the tip, by the way.