# Looking to save an image in java as SVG

Tags: java, image, svg, javax.imageio

I'm trying to export images drawn by a java program as SVG. And it seems like ImageIO doesn't support SVG. Is there something else I could use?

Comment: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

Comment: [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/); [SVG Generator](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html); [Export JPanel to vector graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811916/export-jpanel-to-vector-graphics); [JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/) - do your research, take your pick

Comment: @MadProgrammer I noticed when I was looking at JFreeSVG that it utilizes the class SVGGraphics2D. Do you know if that is the same class that is on the Batik website? They have the same name so I wasn't sure how the projects were different.

Comment: @KaitJardine No, I would say they are different. One reason why there are a number of "other" SVG libraries is because Batik, while comprehensive, is all HUGE in it's byte size

Comment: Voting to close, as library recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow. Please ask over at [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) though.